# Why {} used in TestNg Parameter annotation syntax

Tags: testng

I am wondering why syntax of `@parameter({"a,"b"})` in `testNG` have this additional {} brackets.

My research on this topic may be because we have to specify multiple data here.

What makes me think that reason to use `{}` in parameter is different is in `@Test` we can pass multiple data like `@Test(priority=1, enabled=true)` and we don't use `{}` here `in@Test`.

Please help me to understand this,whether my thinking is in right direction or there's more behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets are used for arrays/lists.

In **org.testng.annotations.Parameters** of TestNG you can see that there is just one method declaration which returns String[]:

```
/**
 * The list of variables used to fill the parameters of this method.
 * These variables must be defined in your testng.xml file.
 * For example
 * <p>
 * <code>
 * &#064;Parameters({ "xmlPath" })<br>
 * &#064;Test<br>
 * public void verifyXmlFile(String path) { ... }<br>
 * </code>
 * <p>and in <tt>testng.xml</tt>:<p>
 * <code>
 * &lt;parameter name="xmlPath" value="account.xml" /&gt;<br>
 * </code>
 */
public String[] value() default {};
```

And in comparison to that you can see in **org.testng.annotations.Test** of TestNG that i.e. **priority** returns int:

```
/**
 * The scheduling priority. Lower priorities will be scheduled first.
 */
int priority() default 0;
```